# Create function to count values across list of columns

Tags: r, function, count, apply

R folks:

I have a dataframe with many sets of columns. Each set is a bank of survey items. I would like to count the number of columns in each set having a certain value.  I wrote a function to do this but it results in a list of repeated values that is appended to my dataframe.

```
df<- structure(list(RespondentID = c(6764279930, 6779986023, 6760279439, 
6759243066), 
                q1 = c(3L, 3L, 4L, 1L), 
                q2 = c(2L, 2L, 4L, 4L), 
                q3 = c(4L, 2L, 4L, 5L), 
                q0010_0004 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L)),
                    .Names = c("RespondentID", "q1", "q2", "q3", "q4"), 
            row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")


group1<-c("q1","q2","q3","q4")

# Objective: Count number of ratings==4 for each row
# Make function that receives list of columns & 
# then returns ONE column in dataframe with total # columns 
# having certain value (in this case, 4)
countcol<-function(colgroup) {
    s<-subset(df, select=c(colgroup)) #select only the columns designated by list
    s$sum<-Reduce("+", apply(X=s,1,FUN=function(x) (sum(x==4, na.rm = TRUE)))) # count instances of value==4
    s2<-subset(s,select=c(sum))  # return ONE column with result for each row 
    return(s2$sum)  }

countcol(group1)
```

My function, `countcol` runs without errors but as stated above results in what appears to be a transposed list of results for each row.  I would like to have ONE number for each row that indicates the count of values.

I attempted various apply functions here but could not prevail.  Anyone have a tip?

Thanks!

Comment: you have written a _good question_. if you provide your desired result, it will be a _great question_. also, is `sum(df[group1] == 1)` what you're looking for?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you should be able to use the `which()` function to do this quite easily:  `length(which(s == 4))`

Comment: `df$new <- apply(df[group1], 1, function(x) length(which(x == 4)))` does everything you need.

Comment: @LAP if that's what OP wants, `rowSums(df[group1]==4)` is another option

Comment: Yep, @MKR was also on to it, just needs to switch cols for rows. This is probably the best solution.

Comment: @bouncyball Perhaps you are right. Mentioned of `group` has slightly confused us.

Comment: Everyone, thanks!  @LAP and @bouncyball's rowSums did the trick.  I found similar ideas here yesterday but they didn't quite do the trick!  The `colgroup` is necessary on my end because I have several groups of columns that I need to pass through the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rowSums` can give you results OP is looking for. This return count of `ratings==4` for each group.

```
rowSums(df[2:5]==4)

#1 2 3 4 
#1 0 3 1
```

OR just part of function from OP can give answer.

```
apply(df[2:5], 1, function(x)(sum(x==4)))
#1 2 3 4 
#1 0 3 1
```

Comment: It's about `rowSums`, though.

Comment: @LAP Probably you are correct. But it seems OP is looking for count of rating for each group i.e. `q1, q2, q3 and q4`.

Comment: From OP's code: `# Objective: Count number of ratings==4 for each row`

Comment: @LAP I agree but at the same time he has mentioned about group. I think either `colSums` for `rowSums` should be good enough for him.

Comment: Right, rowSums is what  I need.  Thanks again.  Followup question: why was my OP code NOT producing a single column result?

Comment: The `Reduce` was obsolete. Your `apply` already produced the column, with `Reduce` you summed up this column into a single value. Another tip for the future when writing functions: always try to stay flexible, therefore don't use static objects like `df` in your function, but use additional parameters (in this case `function(colgroup, df)`.

Comment: @Lap You are absolutely correct!! There was no need of `Reduce`. Otherwise function from OP would have worked.

Comment: @MKR, switch to `rowSums` in your answer, so OP can accept it.